# Use serializer in Django (GeoDjango) to include both model field and some related ForeignKey fields

Tags: python, django, serialization, geojson, geodjango

In my Django project, I have two model **Home** and **Tenant**. model Home is based on geodjango model and has a PointField. Model Tenant has the person information, and also has a ForeignKey to a Home.

```py
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.gis.db import models as geomodels

class Home(geomodels.Model):
    location = models.PointField()
    code = models.IntegerField()
    #  many other fields

class Tenant(models.Model):
    home = models.ForeignKey(Home, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    person_name = models.TextField()
    #  many other fields
```

I use serializer to turn a Queryset of **Home**s into geojson. The thing is, I want to also include some fields of the last **Tenant** model object of each well in that geojson, too (As they are home fields, but with a prefix `tenant__`  to have seperated name from original home fields).

I also prefer not to use Django-Rest-Framework.
Could you help me?